# Encajar imágenes con html y css

Tags: html, css, imagen

Tengo un espacio limitado para mostrar una imagen, por ejemplo de 100x50px.

Si intento mostrar imágenes con otra proporción, me salen en el centro, con los espacios superior e inferior en blanco.

Una imagen, por ejemplo de 50x100, se podria hacer que se ampliara y llenara el 100x50? con el mismo aspecto, ratio, solamente mostrando la parte central? Sin deformarla, ni que aparezcan espacios negros, en arriba/abajo o a los lados, solo que llene el div de 100x50.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera imagen, me gustaría que encajara sin deformarse, que se viera en ese caso la parte central. Espero haberme explicado, seria para html, css y/o js.

Codigo:

```
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 540px; margin-right: 30px;"><div class="card">

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1b222e;
}
```

Comment: Modificado el enunciado

Comment: Puedes crear un contenedor con las medidas que necesitas y colocar dentro la imagen, aplicando la propiedad [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer que la imagen ocupe todo el espacio que reservaste para ella debes primero hacer que rellene dicho espacio dándole 100% de ancho y alto. A continuación con la propiedad css "object-fit" le pides que rellene el espacio con su valor a cover. Esto hará que se comporte como lo haría un fondo que debe rellenar el espacio.

La primera foto tienen una proporción más alta que ancha, mientras que la segunda es más ancha que alta... sin embargo ambas rellenan el hueco para la misma.

```
.img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Dejo un ejemplo.

```css
/* Código de aproximación al ejemplo */
* {
  font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.fila {
  display: flex;
}
.bloque {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.bloque-img {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc
}
.bloque-contenidos {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
/* Aquí la solución concreta a tu pregunta */
.img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>La imágenes se ajustan al su hueco:</h3>
<div class="fila">
  <div class="bloque">
    <div class="bloque-img"><img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/cine/images/f/f8/Fight-Club-1999.jpg" class="img"></div>
    <div class="bloque-contenidos">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bloque">
    <div class="bloque-img"><img src="https://larepublica.pe/resizer/-htZ4aLEzZknG2oayOtY9_OZ9jA=/1250x735/top/smart/cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/gruporepublica/FZRBC5ZT75DIBNGLSOC3GM6KBQ.jpg" class="img"></div>
    <div class="bloque-contenidos">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Como ves las imágenes tienen distinta proporción:</h3>
<div class="fila" style="align-items: flex-start">
    <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/cine/images/f/f8/Fight-Club-1999.jpg" style="max-width: 290px; height: auto; margin: 10px">
    <img src="https://larepublica.pe/resizer/-htZ4aLEzZknG2oayOtY9_OZ9jA=/1250x735/top/smart/cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/gruporepublica/FZRBC5ZT75DIBNGLSOC3GM6KBQ.jpg" style="max-width: 290px; height: auto; margin: 10px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

me encontré con un problema muy similar hace un año, la forma de solucionarlo, y lograr que tengas un `<div>` con determinado aspect ratio, es crear un pseudo elemento dentro del div y agregarle un `padding` ya sea `bottom` o `top`. Por ejemplo, para lograr esa relación de aspecto `100px` de ancho y `50px` de alto, requieres un `padding` del `50%`.

Una vez que se obtiene la relación de aspecto deseada, basta con agregar tu imagen como fondo, centrarla y ajustarla.

Te dejo algunos ejemplos de código.

Ten en mente que puedes hacerlo más responsivo y en lugar de `100px` fijos de ancho, puedes usar porcentajes, y si deseas hacer elementos dinámicos, basta con cambiar la propiedad `background-image` desde `js`.

¡Espero haber ayudado!

```css
div.imageA {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://www.terranovacnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/shutterstock_538309816-scaled.jpg");
}

div.imageA:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

div.imageB {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://www.terranovacnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/shutterstock_538309816-scaled.jpg");
}

div.imageB:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
}

div.imageC {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://www.terranovacnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/shutterstock_538309816-scaled.jpg");
}

div.imageC:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageA"></div>
<br/>
<div class="imageB"></div>
<br/>
<div class="imageC"></div>
```